# Looking for the title to a cyberpunk book from 80-90's that mentioned Jesus was a terrorist

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

I have been trying to find the title of the book, the main guy was a bodyguard and it was set during a US-Russian land war. It mentioned the Dead Sea Scrolls and they found out Jesus was a terrorist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like *["Live from Golgotha"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_from_Golgotha%3a_the_Gospel_according_to_Gore_Vidal)* by Gore Vidal.
Here's another [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CVDYZ0K) with a better synopsis.
It contains a hacker from the 20th Century deleting Christianity and time travel back to past to view the crucifixion.
And (spoiler)

> As you mentioned: Jesus turns out to be the terrorist

Comment: That was what this question reminded me of as well, but there is no US-Russian land war in there, nor is the 'main guy' a bodyguard.

Answer (score 2):

Might be Jack Womack's *Ambient*.  O'Malley, the main character, is a bodyguard.  Christianity has been replaced by the worship of Elvis following the discovery in the Dead Sea Scrolls that Jesus was just an actor who'd been paid by the Romans (I think).